# Is there a "simple" way to factor particular integers using elementary curves?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, algebraic-curves, sieve-theory

Let ***l*** and ***m*** be consecutive integers, where ***l*** represents the floor of the square root of a whole number **N** that is not a perfect square. Are there any *elementary* curve structures that *might* allow ***l*** or ***m*** to be pinpointed so as to facilitate a non-trivial factorisation of **N**, without having to divide by values in a factor base?

If so, is it possible to qualify the characteristics of a class of **N**, for which this may be feasible?

**Edit 18/11/21**

The idea was to try and keep this question as simple as possible in order to gather responses.  Perhaps a little reformulation of the question may keep it alive.

Is there any basic factoring methodology that is *characterised* by its ability to locate (potentially) either the floor or the ceiling of a whole number as an output of a distinct polynomial? In so doing, does it enable the index point of the  discovery to be employed so as to offer up a **non-trivial** **two factor decomposition** of the whole number in a routine manner?

Comment: Do you mean the elliptic curve method to find factors upto $30-40$ digits of a given positive integer ?

Comment: @peter  No, I am wondering about alternatives to ECM and the Quadratic Sieve. Perhaps something that only works in particular circumstances, but theoretically is unbounded.

Comment: "in particular circumstances" - surely. But they are so restrictive that only very special large numbers can be easily factored. In general, the methods you mentioned are the best known and also the only known more or less efficient methods.